# What does it mean to be uniformly allocated in Rust?

Tags: rust

In [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/first-layout.html), the author claims that this code is uniformly allocated. What does that mean?

```
struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: List,
}

pub enum List {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means that all `Node` objects are allocated on the heap (via `Box`), while no `List` objects are boxed (or need to be boxed), though they may be part of a boxed `Node`. This particular representation has the effect that there is exactly one heap allocation per node, and no heap allocations for links to `Empty`.

When operating on lists, we have to manipulate the nodes. In particular, it may be necessary to *move* a node from one list to another. If you had a mix of boxed and unboxed nodes, then transferring ownership of a node from one list to another either involves unboxing and reboxing the node (i.e. allocating a new box and freeing the old one), or writing duplicate or moderately complicated generic code to box/unbox only if necessary. On the other hand, if you always have a `Box<Node>`, then it's much simpler to handle: just move the whole `Box<Node>` (which only copies a pointer).