# Is the first Cons of a boxed List on the stack?

Tags: rust

I was [reading about the `Box` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-01-box.html) and the `Cons` list provided in that chapter:

```
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}
```

I get why Rust doesn't allow to put another `List` inside `List` (refer to listing 15-2) and I also get how `Box<List>` fixes the problem (refer to listing 15-5).

Since `List` is put in a `Box`, does that mean only the FIRST `Cons` will be on the stack with a pointer to `List` in the heap? What about remaining `Cons`? Will they be on the stack? How can they be on the stack when the `List` is in heap? Or are they in the heap (that doesn't sound nice)?

Comment: The standard library documentation on [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html), or its corresponding [module-level documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html), should answer the second part of the question. All boxes are allocated in the heap.

Comment: Strongly related: [What does it mean to be uniformly allocated in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48179328/3650362)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The first `Cons` can be created on the stack, but subsequent linked `Cons` would be allocated on the heap because they're indirected through `Box` which represents a type allocated on the heap. This is assuming you create the first `Cons` naturally/normally, on the stack, but you can of course also create it on the heap through `Box` as well, in which case they would all be on the heap even the first `Cons`.